# Pronunciation of "轧" in 富顺(县)?

Tags: pronunciation

《[富顺方言](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B06XTC2BJK/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_zh_CN=%E4%BA%9A%E9%A9%AC%E9%80%8A%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99&keywords=%E5%AF%8C%E9%A1%BA%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80&qid=1564377852&s=gateway&sr=8-1)》has an entry that reads:

> 【轧】
>   读音：ōā（连读）
>   释义：碾压，轧扎。
>   举例：1、小心车子轧斗人！
>   2、有一道菜叫“轧海椒”，下饭安逸得板。

The thing that is confusing me is the:

> 读音：ōā（连读）

I've checked in the actual print edition of the book and actually it seems that the Kindle edition gives more information the book only prints:

> 读音：oa（连读）

without any diacritics.

What would `ōā（连读）` even sound like? It seems more likely to be a mistake than anything else. Any ideas on the pronunciation of "轧" in 富顺(县)?

Comment: Assuming it's *not* a mistake, I would presume that **ōā** is close to or a corruption of something that sounds like 挖. 軋 is constructed as 烏黠切 in 廣韻, leading to [this array](http://jf.xmu.edu.cn:8085/ap/?q=%E7%83%8F%E9%BB%A0) of possible modern pronunciations. If you then search up [dialectical information on something like 挖](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8C%96#Pronunciation), you get dialectical Rominsations like **wa**, **va**, **ua**, and **oa**.

Comment: @droooze I was thinking soft "w" + "a" would make more sense. 我 sometimes just gets written "o" by people who are really soft with their double-u's.

Comment: Well, that's assuming that the print is a mistake :)

Comment: If you asked me to pronounce "ōā (連讀)", I would start off with a glottal stop. An initial 'o' does not sound like an initial 'w' at all, if these guys pay strict attention to orthography.

Comment: @droooze Definitely not. These guys are writing dialect pronunciations with Mandarin tone-marks/diacritics.

Comment: 《成都方言》mentions that 轧 is pronounced 压.《富顺方言》has another entry that reads: 【妮轧】
读音：nīeā

Comment: I think you almost have your answer, and that it is not really a mistake. Allow for a 烏 initial (not specifying the topolect). Based on what you said about the dictionary’s orthography, I would presume that it’s pronounced using two syllables, and sounds either like 窩啊 or 哦啊 (both first tone).

Comment: Yeah, they do indicate 连读 tho, making it slightly trickier.

Comment: @user3306356 Can you provide any other examples of characters which are transcribed with *oa*? Also, anything with *wa* and with *o*? Not having either book, I can't check their index, but I have an inkling as to what the intended phoneme is meant to be.

Comment: @Michaelyus This has further confused things: 【阿垰】读音：oākā

Comment: @Michaelyus Also this: 【哦喂】读音：owē, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

**A tentative hypothesis:**

It seems like there is a 挖 vs 蛙 split, which the dictionary has tried to notate. There is some kind of difference between the /w/ of 挖 and /ʋ/ of 蛙.

The fortition of /w/ to [ʋ] is attested across all of northern Mandarin, and is particularly prevalent in Beijing and the Northeast. This dictionary *seems* to suggest that this process is incomplete.

I think that the pinyin orthography used by the book has "w" representing /ʋ/, and the "o" representing /w/ instead.

My evidence for this is 娃儿 being transcribed as "wáer (连读)" whilst still having 轧 as "ōā (连读)" in the dictionary.

Comment: I believe the correct pronunciation is: [ŋa⁵⁵], but I'm not sure why /ŋ/ is notated ō. If people are being lazy it's totally expected that [ŋa] would transform into [a](?).

Comment: @user3306356 Thanks for your fieldwork! Actually, if it was originally /ŋ/, then moving to /w/ is entirely expected; it's what happened between Late Middle Chinese and Mandarin (e.g. 我 and 五) and currently happening in Cantonese.

Answer (score 0):

**軋** is actually has 2 pronunciations based on the meaning.
For this case(**輾壓, rolling or flattening out**) should pronounced as "**yà**", like the first syllable of word "**yard**".
For another meaning like **"聚集"(gathering)** or **"借調"(secondment)**, should pronounced as "**gá**", like the first syllable of word "**gallon**".

Check this: [Traditional version](http://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/advExplain1.do?big5=AAEE) or [Simplified version](https://zidian.911cha.com/zi8f67.html)

I'm native Chinese speaker, living in Taiwan currently.

Comment: Uh, I don’t believe you read the question very closely.

Comment: Maybe ōā belongs to the dialect of somewhere mainland China, but based on the meaning in the example, pronounced as yà should not be wrong. OR ōā = yà?(Sorry I don't know the notation explicitly of the upper bar of the ō and ā)

Comment: 這問題是關于富順方言，不是國語